# Таймер. 2 в 1 или 2 отдельных

Tags: java, android, таймер

У меня есть фоновый сервис, с таймером в 100 мс. Но есть функции, которые нужно обрабатывать с другой периодичностью, 5 секунд, 10 минут. Что будет лучше, использовать один таймер, в котором разделять по времени разные процессы, или завести 3 разных таймера?

Работа на андроиде

Comment: вероятно, стоит уточнить критерии «лучшести».

Comment: в плане загрузки процессора, так как операций очень много

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что разница в производительности будет очень маленькая, но, по моему мнению, лучше использовать 1 таймер, т.к. количество обработок функций одно и то же. Зачем тогда 3 таймера вместо 1?)

Comment: Но смотрите, 1 таймер, в нём 2 дополнительные операции. которые проверяют ещё два времени. Таких дополнительных операций по времени может быть ещё несколько

Comment: @ArtyMorris, да, но давайте представим, что у вас будет, допустим, 5 таймеров и в каждом одна проверка определенной операции, в сумме кол-во проверок со всех этих таймеров будет равно кол-ву проверок в одном таймере, но в первом случае у вас будет 5 объектов таймеров, а во втором — один. Может я что-то не правильно понял?

Comment: Да всё верно. Вот мне и интересно, системе обрабатывать проще 5 объектов или 1, но большой

Comment: @ArtyMorris, допустим, у вас 5 обработок разных функций, возьмём один таймер и напишем в нём пять проверок. Пусть одна проверка занимает 5 секунд (для лёгкости вычислений). В сумме один таймер потратит 5*5=25 секунд на проверки. Теперь распределим каждую проверку на 5 таймеров (1 таймер = 1 проверка), каждый таймер потратил 5 секунд на свою проверку и в сумме снова получится 25 секунд. Но: каждый объект занимает определенную ячейку в памяти => либо у вас будет один объект, который будет занимать 1 ячейку, либо 5 объектов, которые будут занимать 5 ячеек. Вроде бы как-то так это работает...

Comment: Теоретически это так, да

Comment: Попробуйте ещё погуглить для большей точности. Пусть даже с другими языками ООП, концепция должна быть одинаковая.

Comment: это еще смотря как написать. Если прогонять через when, то функция вызовется только одна, а проверок от 1 до 3 (в среднем т.е. две)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как вы осуществили свой код? Мне тоже нужно запускать таймер отмеряющий 2 периода (или уже 2 таймера, но так, что бы они работали синхронно), но обязательно в фоновом режиме. Не в фоновом - не проблема, а вот в фоне - никак не могу догадаться. Я уже с ума схожу.